# Trying to compile a function in assembly

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, arm

So, I have this problem:
Write an assembly language function to compute the sum of the first N numbers
between 0 and N. N is passed as an argument to the function. The function will be called as
shown below
Int sumofFirstNNumbers(int N)

And for that I created this assembly code:

```
sub sp, sp, #32

str w0, [sp, 12]

str wzr, [sp, 24]

str wzr, [sp, 28]

.L3:

ldr w1, [sp, 28]

ldr w0, [sp, 12]

cmp w1, w0

bgt .L2

ldr w1, [sp, 24]

ldr w0, [sp, 28]

add w0, w1, w0

str w0, [sp, 24]

ldr w0, [sp, 28]

add w0, w0, 1

str w0, [sp, 28]

b .L3

.L2:

ldr w0, [sp, 24]

add sp, sp, 32

ret
```

but however when I go run that code on Segger, it keeps showing this error,
ARM register expected
 And I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: You might tell us what line is being complained about.

Comment: starts at: Error: ARM register expected -- `str w0,[sp,12]'
4> C:\Users\Alienware\Documents\SEGGER Embedded Studio for ARM Projects\Hw5\Hw5_824113076.S:23: Error: ARM register expected -- `str wzr,[sp,24]'
4> C:\Users\Alienware\Documents\SEGGER Embedded Studio for ARM Projects\Hw5\Hw5_824113076.S:25: Error: ARM register expected -- `str wzr,[sp,28]'
4> C:\Users\Alienware\Documents\SEGGER Embedded Studio for ARM Projects\Hw5\Hw5_824113076.S:29: Error: ARM register expected -- `ldr w1,[sp,28]'

Answer (score 0):

Your code is AArch64, not ARM (32-bit).  Build it with an AArch64 toolchain, not ARM.

Or use ARM registers (`r0` instead of `w0`, etc.).

Also note that ARM doesn't have an architectural zero register so you'll need to create a zeroed register with a `mov` instruction, instead of just using `wzr`.

Or better, don't use memory at all.  sum(i=1..n) only needs a couple registers, counter and accumulator.  And a limit if you count up instead of down.  Did you compile C in debug mode (with an AArch64 compiler) and then hand-copy it into an ARM project?